# Function of Difference/Summation and constrained indices

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations

for fixed $n \geq 0$ (natural number) and $0 \leq i,j \leq n - 1$ i have this function for $0 \leq i + j \leq n - 1$
$$r(i,j) = \left( \sum_{l = 1}^{i + j - 1} l \right) + j$$

otherwise for $n \leq i + j \leq 2n - 2$ i'm trying to define the function by a simmetry respect to the constraint $i + j = n - 1$

specifically what i'm looking is something like $r(n-1,n-1) = n^2 - 1$, $r(n-1,n-2) = n^2 - 2$ and so on...

So for $i+j \geq n - 1$ i want something that $r(i,j) = f(r(n-1-i,n-1-j))$

Is it clear what i mean? I would like to find the function $f$ with the desired properties.

Another properties i'm looking for is the invertibility of the functions (i.e. for given $n$ i want to retrieve the couple (i,j).

Comment: (it is ill posed the problem maybe i will try to state it better)... sorry

Comment: Isn't $\sum_{l=0}^{i+j}l={(i+j)(i+j+1)\over 2}$ good enough?

Comment: No it's not that the problem...

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: I hope it is clearer now...

Comment: It is certainly different.

Answer (score 0):

Your sum is simple:
$$
r(i, j)
  = \sum_{1 \le l \le i + j - 1} l + j
  = \frac{(i + j - 1) (i + j)}{2} + j
$$

I don't understand your "constraint" and "symmetry" tough...

Comment: What is not clear? For which i,j is defined your sum?